# Pass empty string to constructor

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, char, qstring

note: I am still new to c++, and while this may be a simple issue, yet I am unable to find a solution.

Purpose:

I would like to pass an empty string (as one would in java/C#) to my constructor. I receive an error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'ReturnObject::ReturnObject(ResultCode::ClientCode, const char [1])'
         return new ReturnObject(ResultCode::ClientCode::enum_FailedOpeningClientSocket, "");
```

*The `ReturnObject`'s purpose is to encapsulate an `enum` and a `string`.*

**What does this error mean and how can I solve it?**

I have attempted changing my constructor parameter from `QString data` to `char data` and calling with `''` but that resulted in an error `empty character constant`.

**calling code:**

```
return new ReturnObject(ResultCode::ClientCode::enum_FailedSocketConnection, "");
```

**header:**

```
class ReturnObject
{
public:
    ReturnObject(ResultCode enum_code, QString data);

    QString getData();
    ResultCode getCode();

private:
    ResultCode e_code;
    QString data_string;

};
```

**implementation**

```
#include "returnobject.h"

ReturnObject::ReturnObject(){
    data_string="WARN";
}

ReturnObject::ReturnObject(ResultCode enum_code, QString data)
    : e_code(enum_code)
    , data_string(data)
{}

ResultCode ReturnObject::getCode()
{
    return e_code;
}

QString ReturnObject::getData()
{
    return data_string;
}
```

Thanks to **wasthishelpful** and a few comments, I made a tragic logic error which had me looking at the wrong parameter, the solution is that I should casting my enum class `ResultCode` which is the parent class to  one of the nested `class`es, in this case `ClientCode`, as seen below from my enum class header

**enum.h**

```
#ifndef ENUMS_H
#define ENUMS_H

class ResultCode{
public:
    enum class LoginDialogCode{
        enum_LoginSuccess=0,
        enum_InternetOffline=1,
        enum_ServerOffline=2,
        enum_InvalidLoginPass=3,
        enum_EmptyLoginPass=4,
        enum_FailedRetreivingServerList=5,
        enum_TokenFailed=6
    };

    enum class ClientCode{
        enum_SentSuccess=10,
        enum_FailedOpeningClientSocket=11,
        enum_FailedClientSocketConnection=12,
        enum_FailedWritingtoClientSocket=13,
        enum_FailedReadingfromClientSocket=14
    };

    enum class ServerCode{
        enum_ReceivedSuccess=20,
        enum_FailedOpeningListenSocket=21,
        enum_FailedBindingtoListenSocket=22,
        enum_FailedAcceptingListenSocket=23,
        enum_FailedWritingtoListenSocket=24,
        enum_FailedReadingfromListenSocket=25
    };
};

#endif // ENUMS_H
```

Comment: What is the type of `ResultCode::ClientCode::enum_FailedSocketConnection`?

Comment: You expect a `ResultCode` but you pass a `ClientCode`.

Comment: There is no constructor that takes a `ResultCode::ClientCode` parameter, but you've been so sure that the second parameter is the problem that you've ignored the first.

Comment: @GillBates How foolish of me, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @molbdnilo thank you, I did not see that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is not on the second, but on the first parameter. From your question, I guess you have code like this:

```
struct ReturnCode
{
    enum class ClientCode
    {
        enum_FailedSocketConnection,
        // other values
    };
};
```

So you ended up with two declared types: `ReturnCode` and `ReturnCode::ClientCode`. Looking at your constructor declaration:

```
`ReturnObject::ReturnObject(ResultCode enum_code, QString data)`
```

It needs an object of type `ReturnCode` as first parameter, while looking at your call:

```
ReturnObject(ResultCode::ClientCode::enum_FailedSocketConnection, "")
```

You pass an object of type `ReturnCode::ClientCode` as first parameter.

You may change your code like this:

```
class ReturnObject
{
public:
    ReturnObject(ResultCode::ClientCode enum_code, QString data);

    QString getData();
    ResultCode::ClientCode getCode();

private:
    ResultCode::ClientCode e_code;
    QString data_string;

};
```

Once you are here. You may consider taking the enumeration out of `ResultCode`:

```
enum class ClientCode
{
    enum_FailedSocketConnection,
    // other values
};

class ReturnObject
{
public:
    ReturnObject(ClientCode enum_code, QString data);

    QString getData();
    ClientCode getCode();

private:
    ClientCode e_code;
    QString data_string;

};
```

This follows the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): "Flat is better than nested". IMHO this is also true in C++.

**EDIT:**

From your comments, we're here on an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and your code needs to be redesign. Here is a first proposition:

```
#include <type_traits>

enum class ClientCode{
    // ...
    enum_FailedClientSocketConnection=12,
    // ...
};

template<typename T>
struct ReturnObject
{
    static_assert(std::is_enum<T>::value, "T should be an enum");

    const T e_code;
    const QString data_string;
};

template<typename T>
ReturnObject<T> make_return_object(T e_code, std::string data_string)
{
    return ReturnObject<T>{e_code, data_string};
}

// usage

return make_return_object(
    ClientCode::enum_FailedClientSocketConnection, ""
);
```

I removed the accessors `getData` and `getCode` for public const members: they are just read, and should not change for a given return object, so let them be public, with the const qualifier to prevent modification.

I used templates to represent the code, with `static_assert` to check the given type is an enumeration.

The drawbacks are:

- You can pass any enumeration, not only your result codes.
- `make_return_object` will return a different type for each different enumeration.

Comment: Hell yeah ! Thanks. One question though, you are almost correct with your derived code, see my update, I have a nested enum.  I need cast my `ResultCode::enum_FailedOpeningClientSocket` as a `ResultCode::ClientCode` object. How should this be done, rather which should I use, dynamic or static?

Comment: Neither `dynamic_cast` nor `static_cast`: a nested type is not related to its "nesting" type and there can **not** be cast between them, as you could have when using inheritance. The nesting type acts here like a namespace with `private` and `protected` options. Why do you need `ResultCode`? Unless you want to pass any enum nested in `ResultCode`as argument to your functions, but I can't see the point here: if you need a `ClientCode`, you should not allow to pass anything else, and the way to do that is to declare the argument as a `ClientCode`

Comment: infact that is exactly why I need `ResultCode`, since I will using this ReturnObject in a few different classes, I require a class that I can insert any enum from `ResultCode` and a supporting string/(char array). I just realized I do not require `ResultCode` as a `enum` but as a `struct` as you pointed out. But since I can insert any `enum` from `ResultCode`, I am required to typecast it do the appropriate `enum class`. That is what I am refering to, should this be a normal cast like `(ResultCode::ClientCode)ResultCode::ClientCode::enum_Failed...`. I am testing this now...

Comment: That should **NOT** be a cast :) You are here in a wrong design. I will propose you an answer, but I can't today

Comment: Thank you for the trouble, I have resorted to combining all enums into one class, for the moment. I eagerly await your proposed solution/new design, I would love to get a fresh opinion on this!

Comment: I edited my answer with a first proposition. I guess it will be incomplete for you, but, without details on how you're using `ReturnObject`, your question is too broad. Maybe you will need a real type erasure like `variant`, or `any`. Feel free to edit your question with a complete use case